# SwiftUI - List doesn't update when I transfer data from view to another

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I'm trying to send data from FirstView to the List in the struct called myMoodList.
My issue is once the data sent to the myMoodList, it doesn't add to the List.
So I have put dummy button in navigationBar so I can add row that contains the data.

Here's my Code,

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView{
        VStack{
            Text(currentMood)

}
    }.navigationBarItems(trailing: NavigationLink(destination:MyMoodList(currentMood: currentMood)) {
        Text("Next")
    }
    ).navigationBarTitle("Mood People", displayMode: .inline)
}
```

So currentMood is String and its value "Happy".

Here's my main view.

```
struct moodStructure: Identifiable,Decodable {

let id = UUID()
let myMood: String
}

class MoodViewModel: ObservableObject {
@Published var moodStatus = "Test on MoodObjectModel"
@Published var moodArray: [moodStructure] = [
    .init(myMood: "Happy"),
    .init(myMood: "Sad")
]
func addItem(moodStatus: String) {
    moodArray.append(moodStructure(myMood: moodStatus))
    print(moodArray.capacity)
}
func didChange() {
    self.moodStatus = "Test inside did change"
}
}


 struct MyMoodList: View {


@ObservedObject var moodVM = MoodViewModel()
@State var currentMood: String

var body: some View {

    NavigationView {
        List() {
            ForEach(moodVM.moodArray,id: \.myMood) { item in

                HStack {
                    VStack {
                        Text(item.myMood)
                        Text("Feb/3/2020")
                            .font(.callout)
                    }
                    Spacer()
                    Text(">")
                        .fontWeight(.semibold)
                }
            }

        }.navigationBarTitle("Tracker")
            .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: {
                self.moodVM.addItem(moodStatus: self.currentMood)
            }) {
                Image(systemName: "plus")
            })
    }
}}
```

So the MyMoodList struct has navigationBarButton, I put it just to make sure that the data has successfully sent from first view to MyMoodList.
but what I want is once the user moves from the firstView to the MyMoodList, it adds automatically to the list. I don't want to use the button so I can add it to the list.

I don't know if the List doesn't update automatically, or the list loads first before the items has added to moodArray inside Class MoodViewModel.

Thank you.

UPDATE:

on my FirstView I have

```
.navigationBarItems(trailing: NavigationLink(destination:MyMoodList(currentMood: currentMood, addNewPost: true))
```

on MyMoodList Class
I added `@State var addNewPost: Bool`

```
.onAppear() {
        if self.addNewPost == true {
            self.moodVM.addItem(moodStatus: self.currentMood)
            self.addNewPost = false
        } else {
            print("Nothing !!")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use .`onAppear` modifier on `NavigationView` of your `MyMoodList` struct to add the string to the array.

```
struct ContentView: View {
var currentMood = "Happy1"
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        VStack{
            Text(currentMood)

            NavigationLink(destination:MyMoodList(currentMood: currentMood)) {
                Text("Next")
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Mood People", displayMode: .inline)
    }
}}

struct moodStructure: Identifiable,Decodable {
  let id = UUID()
  let myMood: String
}

class MoodViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var moodStatus = "Test on MoodObjectModel"
    @Published var moodArray: [moodStructure] = [
        .init(myMood: "Happy"),
        .init(myMood: "Sad")
    ]
    func addItem(moodStatus: String) {
        moodArray.append(moodStructure(myMood: moodStatus))
        print(moodArray.capacity)
    }
    func didChange() {
        self.moodStatus = "Test inside did change"
    }
  }

struct MyMoodList: View {

@ObservedObject var moodVM = MoodViewModel()
var currentMood: String

var body: some View {

    NavigationView {
        List() {
            ForEach(moodVM.moodArray,id: \.myMood) { item in

                HStack {
                    VStack {
                        Text(item.myMood)
                        Text("Feb/3/2020")
                            .font(.callout)
                    }
                    Spacer()
                    Text(">")
                        .fontWeight(.semibold)
                }
            }

        }.navigationBarTitle("Tracker")
            .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: {
                self.moodVM.addItem(moodStatus: self.currentMood)
            }) {
                Image(systemName: "plus")
            })
    }
    .onAppear {
        if !self.moodVM.contains(self.currentMood) {
        self.moodVM.addItem(moodStatus: self.currentMood)
        }
    }
}}
```

Comment: I'm going to revise the whole answer.

Comment: Check the new answer out

Comment: Thank you so much, I will check it out and let you know.

Comment: Every time I open MyMoodList it adds new row. so I updated my question. Do you think it's valid now ?.

Comment: In that case you can check if the array has the element or not. check updated answer I used `contains` for the array. no need a new `state var` for checking.

Comment: Do you think I have to put this  if !self.moodVM."moodArray", so I can access the array. Also I'm getting error say I have to Insert 'where: '.